# how to make sonar show changes since last one day instead of last 5 days or 1 months?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

When I click on a project Sonar is analyzing, it shows me a dropdown at the top saying "`Time changes`" and the options are

- since last build
- since 5 days
- since 1 month

How can I get the changes since the last 1 day, or any arbitrary time ? I am using `Sonar 3.3` as a plugin to `Jenkins 1.487`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called Sonar differential services. There's online documentation that describes how you can modify these options to fit your needs:

In general you can have three global options (common to all projects) and two options for each different project

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views#DifferentialViews-DifferentialViewsSettings

Comment: Sadly, the link died... [Here it is through Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314014717/http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views)